# How to sort number having dash included in it?

Tags: php

> Below array need to sort by planning_no field

```
Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [planning_no] => 100-3
                    [pieces] => 0
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [planning_no] => 100
                    [pieces] => 0
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [planning_no] => 100-2
                    [pieces] => 0
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [planning_no] => 100
                    [pieces] => 148
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [planning_no] => 102
                    [pieces] => 0
                )
            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [planning_no] => 100-1
                    [pieces] => 0
                )
        )
```

> I want array in below format

```
Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [planning_no] => 100
                    [pieces] => 0
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [planning_no] => 100
                    [pieces] => 148
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [planning_no] => 100-1
                    [pieces] => 0
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [planning_no] => 100-2
                    [pieces] => 0
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [planning_no] => 100-3
                    [pieces] => 0
                )
            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [planning_no] => 102
                    [pieces] => 0
                )
        )
```

Comment: not any explanation of dash system. in this link

Comment: Cant you just replace every `-` with a `,` through php replace function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) function.

[See it live here](https://eval.in/563639)

**Working Code:**

```
<?php
$values = array();
$a = new stdClass();
$a->planning_no = '100-3';
$a->pieces = '0';
$values[] = $a;
$a = new stdClass();
$a->planning_no = '100';
$a->pieces = '0';
$values[] = $a;
$a = new stdClass();
$a->planning_no = '100-2';
$a->pieces = '0';
$values[] = $a;
$a = new stdClass();
$a->planning_no = '100';
$a->pieces = '148';
$values[] = $a;
$a = new stdClass();
$a->planning_no = '102';
$a->pieces = '0';
$values[] = $a;
$a = new stdClass();
$a->planning_no = '100-1';
$a->pieces = '0';
$values[] = $a;
$n = array();
if (! empty($values)) {
 foreach ($values as $value) {
  $planning_no = str_replace('-', '.', $value->planning_no);
  $n[] = array('planning_no' => $planning_no, 'pieces' => $value->pieces);
 }
}
array_multisort($n);
$final = array();
if (! empty($n)) {
 foreach ($n as $elem) {
  $planning_no = str_replace('.', '-', $elem['planning_no']);
  $a = new stdClass();
  $a->planning_no = $planning_no;
  $a->pieces = $elem['pieces'];
  $final[] = $a;
 }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($final);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [planning_no] => 100
            [pieces] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [planning_no] => 100
            [pieces] => 148
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [planning_no] => 100-1
            [pieces] => 0
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [planning_no] => 100-2
            [pieces] => 0
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [planning_no] => 100-3
            [pieces] => 0
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [planning_no] => 102
            [pieces] => 0
        )

)
```